# Some basic questions on RDBMSes

Tags: rdbms

I've skimmed thru Date and Silberschatz but can't seem to find answers to these specific questions of mine.

1. If 2 database users issue a query  -- say, 'select * from AVERYBIGTABLE;' -- where would the results of the query get stored in general... i.e., independent of the size of the result set?

   a. In the OS-managed physical/virtual memory of the DBMS server?

   b. In a DBMS-managed temporary file?
2. Is the query result set maintained per connection?
3. If the query result set is indeed maintained per connection, then what if there's connection pooling in effect (by a layer of code sitting above the DBMS)? Won't, then, the result set be maintained per query (instead of per connection)?
4. If the database is changing in realtime while its users concurrently issue select queries, what happens to the queries that have already been executed but not yet (fully) 'consumed' by the query issuers? For example, assume the result set has 50,000 rows; the user is currently iterating at 100th, when parallely another user executes an insert/delete such that it would lead to more/less than 50,000 rows if the earlier query were to be re-issued by any user of the DBMS?
5. On the other hand, in case of a database that does not change in realtime, if 2 users issue identical queries each with identical but VERY LARGE result sets, would the DBMS maintain 2 identical copies of the result set, or would it have a single shared copy?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of this may be specific to Oracle.

1. The full results of the query do not need to copied each user gets a cursor (like a pointer) that maintains which rows have been retrieved, and what rows still need to be fetched. The database will cache as much of data as it can as it reads the data out of the tables. Same principal as two users have read only file handle on file.
2. The cursors are maintained per connection, the data for the next row may or may not already be in memory.
3. Connections for the most part are single threaded, only 1 client can use a connection at a time. If the same query is executed twice on the same connection then the cursor position is reset.
4. If a cursor is open on table that is being updated then the old rows are copied into a separate space (undo in Oracle) and is maintained for the life of the cursor, or at least until it runs out of space to maintain it. (Oracle will give a snapshot too old error)
5. The database will never duplicate the data stored in cache, in Oracle's case with cursor sharing there would a single cached cursor and each client cursor would only have to maintain its position in the cached cursor.

[Oracle Database Concepts](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/toc.htm)

See 8 Memory for questions 1, 2, 5

See 13 Data Concurrency and Consistency (Questions 3, 4)

Comment: Thanks, for your Oracle-specific answer. Would you be able to point me to an Oracle document that best discusses these concepts... in one place?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you don't find this in Date etc is because they could change between DBMS products, there is nothing in the relational model theory about pooling connections to the database or how to maintain the result sets from a query (like caching etc).  The only point which is partially covered is 4 - where the read level would come into play (eg read uncommitted), but this only applies until the result set has been produced.

Comment: I can see, now, why they aren't covered in relational theory texts. But, then, where would I find their answers? In product-specific manuals? JEE is touted to be independent of the underlying DBMSes... which tells me that there is got to be at least some constant concept (or, a set of concepts/assumptions) against which an application developer can choose to program.

Comment: And regarding your response to #4, what happens AFTER the resultset has been produced? (Thanks, btw, for taking the time to respond.)

Comment: JEE like many development frameworks is independent of underlying DBMS, that means that you can connect to many different DBMSes via a standard set of interfaces like ODBC.  So if you want ODBC could provide your set of concepts/assumptions to develop against.  This interface removes the need to know DBMS specific details, like what happens to the result set once produced, but before sent back to the caller, and if you really wanted to know you would have to read up on a specific DBMS, but I don't see what difference it could make to your application.